# How do I call Ruby script from a shell script?

Tags: ruby, shell, nohup

I am trying to write a watchdog for a Ruby application. So far, I have a cron job which is successfully calling a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep adpc.rb ; then
    exit 0
else
    NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y"+"%T" )
    echo "$NOW - CRITIC: ADPC service is down! Trying to initialize..." >> che.log
    cd lib
    nohup ruby adpc.rb &
    exit 0
fi
```

This code runs correctly from command line, but I am not able to make the shell script execute the Ruby script when called from a cron job.

Please any help would be appreciated.

1. The Ruby file has `+x` permissions.
2. The nohup.out file is empty.

**Solution**: replace bare "ruby" command with full path (which ruby output).

Thanks to all for the replies =)

Comment: Are you getting an error of some sort? Is it just not running ruby?

Comment: Found no error. It is just not executing the rb. Can it be possible?

Comment: Ya, for example, if the user who launch the cron job doesn't have "x" permission of the ruby script.

Another hypothesis : when you run your shell script, you might not be in the same directory. So your relative path may not work...

Comment: Have you read the output file of nohup ? nohup.out default

Comment: You are using a "bare" `ruby` call instead of a absolute path to Ruby. Is the cron tab owner root or is Ruby in the path for that user? If not use the full path.

Comment: Full path worked! Thanks TTM =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually caused by an incorrect environment. Check the Ruby output in the created `nohup.out` file and log the stderr of nohup itself to a file.

It's frequently solved by starting the script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will ensure that you run with `bash` instead of `sh`, and that any settings like PATH you've configured in your init files will be set.

Comment: 'Zaxtly. Not having the environment set is a common error that people forget.